# How to Attach event for the DHTLMX Clist cell type?

Tags: dhtmlx, clistbox

I was working on Dhtmlx grid . I used the Clist ( Multi-select-combo-box ) data-type . Once the selection is made , I need to validate the list of the selected items . Can some-one who is familiar can help suggesting how to attach event for the "onChange" for Clist datatype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, such feature is not available.

All changes can be validated only after the closing the CList select box closing.